# Creating Unique Study site plot in Program R

Tags: r, spatial

I am attempting to create a plot of a unique study site in Program R. I utilizing "Wisconsin Stream and Rivers" data as the basal layer. There are five river in the specific study area I am interested in.  I am having troubles showing only two of the rivers in the study area when I attempt to create the plot to show the locations of tagged fish via radio telemetry/gps coordinates. I can either produce a plot with all five, or only one. I cannot seem to create a plot with two specific rivers.

I am new to using R so please let me know if I can provide any further detail.

This is the code I was working with. Specifically, I was trying to filter for "Little Plover River & Unnamed"

```
# Select only River used
Study_Area_Selected <- Study_Area %>%
filter(RIVER_SYS_ == "Little Plover River")
# View study river
ggplot(Study_Area_Selected) + geom_sf(color = "blue") +
theme_classic() + ggtitle("Study Area")
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Keenan, welcome to SO. It would help if you could provide a minimal dataset to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%in%`:

```r
Study_Area %>%
  filter(RIVER_SYS_ %in% c("Little Plover River", "unnamed"))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  RIVER_SYS_           value
  <chr>                <dbl>
1 Little Plover River -0.560
2 unnamed              1.56
```

Or `stringr::str_detect()`:

```r
Study_Area %>%
  filter(str_detect(RIVER_SYS_, "Little Plover River|unnamed"))
```

With example data:

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)

Study_Area <- tibble(RIVER_SYS_ = c("Little Plover River", "foo", "unnamed"),
                     value = rnorm(3))
```